# Docker stats vs runtime memory stats

Tags: docker, go

I'm using docker stats to check the performance of a service (service A) running in a docker container.

I'm running a script that executes a new service each 3 seconds.

Then, service A requests data from these new services and save it.

When I monitor memory usage from docker stats, when the script finishes, I get the RAM's final value of 22.54MiB / 3.852GiB.

I'm also monitoring with runtime.MemStats and it only returns 11MB.

More specifically:`{\"Alloc\":11739792,\"TotalAlloc\":307488272,\"Sys\":31156472,\"Mallocs\":3768022,\"Frees\":3619052,\"LiveObjects\":148970,\"PauseTotalNs\":171105902,\"NumGC\":335,\"NumGoroutine\":543}" source="edge.go:1943"`.

Any ideas why  is this happening?  What's the most reliable source to get memory usage?

Thanks

Comment: "to get memory usage" --- there is number of types of "usage", especially for a runtime with GC, what is your original problem you're solving with those numbers?

Comment: `MemStats` `Alloc` is documented as `Alloc is bytes of allocated heap objects.`

Comment: Shouldn't be similar with the total memory the container is using? @zerkms

Comment: Nope, one is RSS (is it actually? docker documentation does not clarify that), the other is the size of the objects in heap. Imagine you have a 1 Litre bottle of water. You've drunk half of it. You still have 1L bottle, but you have 0.5L of water in it.

Comment: I have an in memory database that saves around 5MB at the end of the script. Docker says the process in the beginning is using 5MB. It seems too much that the process is using 30MB at the end. I'm afraid that something is wrong.. maybe with garbage collector? What do you think? thanks @zerkms

Comment: I think it works as expected. https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2018/12/garbage-collection-in-go-part1-semantics.html